# ¿Por qué no muestra la cantidad de registros actualizados?

Tags: php

Desde un formulario envío valores en matriz para actualizar mi tabla:

```
$codigos = $_POST['codigo'];
$nombres_old = $_POST['nombre_old'];
$nombres_new = $_POST['nombre_new'];

foreach($codigos as $codigo){
    $nombre_old = $nombres_old[$codigo];
    $nombre_new = $nombres_new[$codigo];

    $sql = "UPDATE tabla SET nom_old = '$nombre_old', nom_new = '$nombre_new' WHERE cod = $codigo";
    $sth1 = $BD->prepare($sql);
    $sth1->execute();
}
$_SESSION['CantRegCambiados'] = $sth1->rowCount();
echo $_SESSION['CantRegCambiados'];
```

El UPDATE funciona. Lo que no funciona es mostrar la cantidad de registros actualizados. Siempre me muestra 1 (Así no actualice nada).
El código es integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cambiaría tu código de esta manera, ya que te devuelve siempre `1` al hacer `UPDATE` con `$sth1->rowCount();`:

```
$count = 0;

foreach($codigos as $codigo){

  // tu código   

  if ($sth1->execute()) {

     $count++; // Sumamos uno, si ha sido exitoso el update
  }      
}

$_SESSION['CantRegCambiados'] = $count; // Total de los updates realizados
```

Comment: Analizando el código, puede ser que siempre me muestra 1 porque solo actualiza un registro por cada iteración. Pues en otros update masivos que no están dentro de un bucle, el rowcount() muestra la cantidad correcta de registros procesados.

Comment: @Piropeator - Exacto... así es... saludos